# Add function to laravel Notification

Tags: laravel, function, notifications, addition

I have next Notification class:

```
class WelcomeNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

And I want add some function to this. For example:

```
public function myFunction()
{
    return 'something';
}
```

But $user->notifications->first()->myFunction return nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the [`notifications()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Notifications/HasDatabaseNotifications.php#L10) relation it turns out is a polymorphic relation using the `DatabaseNotification` model. The proper way is to inherit `DatabaseNotification` and write the custom function their.

For example, create **app/DatabaseNotification/WelcomeNotification.php** and inherit `DatabaseNotification` model.

```
namespace App\DatabaseNotification;

use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;

class WelcomeNotification extends DatabaseNotification
{

    public function foo() {
        return 'bar';
    }

}
```

And override the `notifications()` function that uses the `Notifiable` trait:

```
use App\DatabaseNotification\WelcomeNotification;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    ...

    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(WelcomeNotification::class, 'notifiable')
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

    ...

}
```

And now you can call the custom function as follows:

```
$user->notifications->first()->foo();
```